General Formulation of the Change of Variable Formula for Density Determination
I'm interested in understanding the general formulation of the change of variable formula for determining the density of a transformed random variable.
In fact, I am in charge of tutorial sessions and came across the following formula in the professor's lecture:
$$f_{\phi(X)}(y)= f_{X}(\phi^{-1}(y))|\det J_{\phi^{-1}}(y)|.$$
But if we consider for instance $X$ to be uniformly distributed on $]0,2[$ and $\phi$ to be the square root function, this formula doesn't hold as it is. I think a more general formula might be:
$$f_{\phi(X)}(y)= \begin{cases} 
f_{X}(\phi^{-1}(y))|\det J_{\phi^{-1}}(y)|\; \text{if}\; y\in \operatorname{support}(\phi(X))\\0 \; \text{else}
\end{cases}$$
for $\phi$ a $\mathcal{C}^1$-diffeomorphism from $\operatorname{support}(X)$ to $\operatorname{support}(\phi(X))$.
Does this sound correct?
Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Could you give details of why you feel that the formula does not hold in your example? Where the formula does not hold is in fact when $\phi^{-1}(y)$ is not one-to-one and so one gets a sum of terms like the RHS of the formula from the lecture. e.g. $X$ has support $]-1,+1[$ and $\phi(x)=x^2$.
